# Custom Twenty Thirteen fonts?

Tags: theme-twenty-thirteen

Is it possible to change the fonts?
I come from twentyeleven. I am used to declare the fonts in the CSS and upload them in different formats to the sever.

I need to use my own custom fonts...

I found this: [How do I change the fonts in the Twenty Thirteen theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/how-do-i-change-the-fonts-in-the-twenty-thirteen-theme)

But I have no experience in PHP so it's Chinese...

I did manage to de-register the fonts used by using this piece of code in my child functions.php file.

```
function deregister_gfonts_wpse_111190() {
  wp_deregister_style('twentythirteen-fonts');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','deregister_gfonts_wpse_111190',100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've removed the twentythirteen fonts  you can add new ones via your styles.css file using `@font-face`.